# AS3 | Load image from url with loader error

Tags: actionscript-3

My goal is: with one FOR function to set position on 10 MovieClips and show image in MovieClips.

My code:

```
function loadOnePageItems(folderID:int):void {
var it:int=1;
var openURL:String;
var loader:Loader = new Loader();

for (var i:int = 1; i <= loadedXML.folder[folderID].*.length(); i++) {
    openURL = ("http://some_site.com/library/cut_img.php?src=" + loadedXML.folder[folderID].@name + '/' + loadedXML.folder[folderID].item[i-1].@url  + '.' + loadedXML.folder[folderID].item[i-1].@type + '&w=87&h=64');
    loader.load(new URLRequest(openURL));
    MovieClip(mc_library.getChildByName('item_' + i)).showcase.addChild(loader);

    switch (it) {
        case 10 :
            mc_library.item_10.x=189,00;
            mc_library.item_10.y=485,55;
            break;
        case 9 :
            mc_library.item_9.x=63,00;
            mc_library.item_9.y=485,55;
            break;
        case 8 :
            mc_library.item_8.x=189,00;
            mc_library.item_8.y=375,55;
            break;
        case 7 :
            mc_library.item_7.x=63,00;
            mc_library.item_7.y=375,55;
            break;
        case 6 :
            mc_library.item_6.x=189,00;
            mc_library.item_6.y=265,55;
            break;
        case 5 :
            mc_library.item_5.x=63,00;
            mc_library.item_5.y=265,55;
            break;
        case 4 :
            mc_library.item_4.x=189,00;
            mc_library.item_4.y=155,55;
            break;
        case 3 :
            mc_library.item_3.x=63,00;
            mc_library.item_3.y=155,55;
            break;
        case 2 :
            mc_library.item_2.x=189,00;
            mc_library.item_2.y=45,55;
            break;
        case 1 :
            mc_library.item_1.x=63,00;
            mc_library.item_1.y=45,55;
            break;
        default :
            trace("None of the numbers above");
            break;
        }
        it++;
    }
}
```

When i start only last item get image from "loader". Image from library - http://puu.sh/7cjxR.png.

How to fix it ?

Comment: For starters you seem to be declaring all your positions in european format (`number,decimals`) rather than the `number.decimals` format.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: Trace `i` and check if it is really incrementing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is, that you're using just one `Loader` and only changing its url. You should move `loader` declaration into the loop. This will create multiple instances of `Loader` and all images should be delivered.

```
function loadOnePageItems(folderID:int):void {
    var it:int=1;
    var openURL:String;

    for (var i:int = 1; i <= loadedXML.folder[folderID].*.length(); i++) {
        openURL = ("http://some_site.com/library/cut_img.php?src=" 
        + loadedXML.folder[folderID].@name + '/' + loadedXML.folder[folderID].item[i-1].@url  + '.' + loadedXML.folder[folderID].item[i-1].@type + '&w=87&h=64');
        var loader:Loader = new Loader();
        loader.load(new URLRequest(openURL));
        MovieClip(mc_library.getChildByName('item_' + i)).showcase.addChild(loader);

    switch (it) {
        case 10 :
            mc_library.item_10.x=189,00;
            mc_library.item_10.y=485,55;
            break;
        case 9 :
            mc_library.item_9.x=63,00;
            mc_library.item_9.y=485,55;
            break;
        case 8 :
            mc_library.item_8.x=189,00;
            mc_library.item_8.y=375,55;
            break;
        case 7 :
            mc_library.item_7.x=63,00;
            mc_library.item_7.y=375,55;
            break;
        case 6 :
            mc_library.item_6.x=189,00;
            mc_library.item_6.y=265,55;
            break;
        case 5 :
            mc_library.item_5.x=63,00;
            mc_library.item_5.y=265,55;
            break;
        case 4 :
            mc_library.item_4.x=189,00;
            mc_library.item_4.y=155,55;
            break;
        case 3 :
            mc_library.item_3.x=63,00;
            mc_library.item_3.y=155,55;
            break;
        case 2 :
            mc_library.item_2.x=189,00;
            mc_library.item_2.y=45,55;
            break;
        case 1 :
            mc_library.item_1.x=63,00;
            mc_library.item_1.y=45,55;
            break;
        default :
            trace("None of the numbers above");
            break;
        }
        it++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm noob in actionscript do you can give me example of code ?